# Looking for orphaned subtitles

Tags: python

I want to look through my video files and delete orphan subtitles and empty directories. I'm a beginner in python, and did only the looking for orphaned subtitles part, but my code doesn't look through subdirectories but gives me multiple results for rootdir. So I'm guessing one of my loops is wrong.
Here is my code, thanks for your advices :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

rootdir='/mnt/nas'

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for filename in files:

        # looking for subtitles files
        if filename.endswith('.srt'):
            filename_srt = os.path.splitext(filename)

            # looking for video files
            for filename_other in files:
                if filename_other.endswith(('avi', 'mkv', 'mp4')):
                    filename_other_vid = os.path.splitext(filename_other)

                    # if the video name isn't included in a subtitle name
                    if filename_other_vid[0] not in filename_srt[0]:
                        print(filename_srt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is once you iterate files , you are again iterating it for `filename_other_vid` which is not required. Once you iterate files you can extract both subtitles and video name in one loop.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

rootdir='/mnt/nas'

for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for filename in files:

        # looking for subtitles files
        if filename.endswith('.srt'):
            filename_srt = os.path.splitext(filename)

        # looking for video files
        for filename_other in files:
            if filename_other.endswith(('avi', 'mkv', 'mp4')):
                filename_other_vid = os.path.splitext(filename_other)

        # if the video name isn't included in a subtitle name
        if filename_other_vid[0] not in filename_srt[0]:
            print(filename_srt)
```

Comment: Maybe add a little explanation? A simple "try this" and code (which may be correct) shed little light on the actual problem or mistake, and we're all here to learn, aren't we? ;)

Comment: @ChristianKönig absolutely, I respect your opinion, let me add explanation,  you are my very first buddy, remember :)